# Awkward Date Format in Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm having trouble parsing this date:

```
Satu, 30 Octo 2010 06:00:00 EDT
```

I think it would be

```
EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
```

but it is not working. I would like to format it to

```
Saturday, October 30, 2010
```

I've been looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html as my resource

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: How about some pre-processing? Convert `Satu, 30 Octo 2010 06:00:00 EDT` to `Sat, 30 Oct 2010 06:00:00 EDT`, i.e. simply remove 3rd and 12th char. Make life simpler! (If you are fine with regex, you can generalize it as well using the position of `,` and char-type.)

Comment: Ok so i'll just process it as a string first. It is a very strange date format anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'd ditch the `Satu,` and just parse from then on. You don't need it and can always use `Calendar` to figure out day of the week/month/year. See [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) for what StringUtils is.

```
String dateString = "Satu, 30 Octo 2010 06:00:00 EDT";

Map<String, String> weirdMonthMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
weirdMonthMap.put("Janu", "Jan");
//...
weirdMonthMap.put("Octo", "Oct");

for (String key: weirdMonthMap.keySet()) {
    dateString = StringUtils.replace(dateString, key, weirdMonthMap.get(key));
}

String[] pieces = StringUtils.split(dateString, ',');
if (pieces.length != 2)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Whoa! " + dateString);

dateString = pieces[1];

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(" dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

System.out.println( format.parse(dateString) );
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I believe the problem is that `Octo` isn't a recognized abbreviation for October, nor `Satu` for Saturday. `SimpleDateFormat` seems to work by having a specific set of supported names, rather than by trying to match string-prefixes.

Comment: Yeah, you're right I missed the Octo. It'd probably be easiest to do a global string replace or Regex

Answer (score 0):

```
Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.
```

MMM doesn't mean "first three letter".

Both MMM and MMMMMMMMMMMMMM are same.

So your input should be like "Oct" or "October"